# Updating the Global Variable

Tags: swift

I have defined a global variable in my view controller. The second function needs to use the first functions's product. How can the functions talk to each other?

var myPhotoArray : [UIImage] !

```
func loadImages() { 
             for object in objects {
                let photoToView = object["imageFile"] as PFFile

                        photoToView.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                            (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                            if (error == nil){

                                var hereData = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                myPhotoArray.append(hereData!)
                            }    
                                                                         func numberOfImageView() {

    if photoArray.count > 0 {

    for i in 0...photoArray.count-1{

  var widthPlace = CGFloat(i * 245)
  var myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(widthPlace, 32, 245, 245))
        myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(myPhotoArray[i])")
        scroller.addSubview(myImageView)

        }                                                                                                       basically, second function needs to use the product of the first function .
```

Bests,

Answer (score 0):

You really should have included some more code. Anyway, from your description, I think the model would work.

If a variable is declared globally (and not inside the scope of a particular function), then both functions should be able to access it.

```
var arr = [1, 2]

func add() {
    arr[1] = 2
}

func modify() {
    arr[1] = 0
}
```

In this case, the first function can update the global variable.

Comment: Okay this is not what I exactly asked. I put more code here.